# SQLite on iPhone - Get final query string with parameters after binding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I would like to get the final SQL query, with parameter values bound (replaced) for debugging. It is a rather large and complex query (some joins, and about 20 parameters). Just wondered if it was possible to access the final query passed to the sqlite db.

```
//PSEUDO CODE

theSQL = "SELECT a,b,c FROM myTable where aField = ?";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDb, theSQL, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, myUTF8stringParam, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

theSQLwithBoundParams = //<<<--- here is missing what I look for ;)
NSLog(@"Perpared Statement with params: %@", theSQLwithBoundParams);

...
```

I already looked around on the web and the sqlite documentation without luck.
For reference, I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424042/how-to-log-sqlite-queries-on-iphone) here on stackoverflow. It is almost a year old - so I thought asking again should be ok…

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You migth want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607368/sql-query-logging-for-sqlite) question. Basically, you can write your own
`sqlite3_trace` to record the latest query.

Answer (score 0):

Starting on SQLite 3.14 there is the [`sqlite3_expanded_sql()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/expanded_sql.html) function.

You can call it inside a callback registered with the [`sqlite3_trace_v2()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/trace_v2.html) function.